# hditutil tool will not convert .iso to .img?

Tags: terminal, macos, file-conversion

This is not working for me! Will someone clarify why?

Here's the command I'm using:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRAW -o /Users/Jacob/Desktop/destination_file.img /Users/Jacob/Downloads/debian-8.2.0-amd64-DVD-3.iso
```

And here's what terminal returns:

```
Usage: hdiutil convert -format <format> -o <outfile> [options] <image>
       hdiutil convert -help
```

Comment: man hdutil only lists four character formats - however it also has the image as raw first parameter so could be wrong

Comment: Unfortunately, almost every Q&A forum has this posted as the way to convert an ISO to IMG in order to create a bootable USB for Linux OS installation. If you have a more effective method, please elaborate.

Comment: What does UDRAW stand for and which site shows this - googling gives me lines using UDRW as per man page

Comment: @rbApostate The raw img format you mention is an image of a real CD including the CIRC data (similar to the bin/cue files). It doesn't make **any** sense to convert an iso to an img file because the source is no physical CD.

Comment: @rbApostate, Did you try running `hdiutil convert -help` as the `Usage` output shows? It shows the proper Usage and Image Formats to form a proper command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper command to use is:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o /Users/Jacob/Desktop/destination_file.img /Users/Jacob/Downloads/debian-8.2.0-amd64-DVD-3.iso
```

([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick) with an OS X how-to)

In UDRW RW doesn't stand for RAW but for R/W (readable and writable)!